# Webservice date format should be changed to required format in iOS

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I am working on one iOS app. I got response from service with date field mentioned below. I want  to show the date in my required format, but I am unable to do that. I have tried lot of ways.

```
<DateModified>2014-07-10T17:18:41.447+00:00</DateModified>    // Present
<DateModified>2014-07-10 17:18:41</DateModified>            // Required
```

Above mentioned date should be show in the required format that shown there.This is the code that I am using currently.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.'SSSZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:myString];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *localDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Date=%@", localDateString);
```

Comment: What is the output? You seem to use the good format for the first one (present date format), but the second one doesn't match what you want (required date format)

Comment: No no that is not the case.I am using the above mentioned two methods for conversion of date.

Comment: 2014-07-10T17:18:41.447+00:00   is the string object.I want to convert that to 2014-07-10 17:18:41 by removing last zeros and dot after seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    [df setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/London"]; //set here the timezone you want
    [df setTimeZone:timeZone];

    NSDate *inputDate = [df dateFromString: dateString];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    NSString *inputValue = [df stringFromDate:inputDate];
```

Comment: No Retro its not working.I have checked it with your code but date shows 5.30 hours more than than we assigned input.

Comment: While converting from that response date to required date Its not showing the correct date and time.

Comment: because there is a time zone difference which you need to set according to your requirement, i have added the example in my answer